# Story telling: me and SHE (or) me and HER?

Tags: personal-pronouns

Usage (1)

> Me - "You're beautiful."
> **She** - "Thank you. You're so kind."

Usage (2)

> Me - "You're beautiful."
> **Her** - "Thank you. You're so kind."

Which one is correct please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*She* or *I* is the subject of a verb, *her* or *me* an object of a verb or preposition.  Wherever *me* is correct, *her* is also correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not fluent in English. Therefore if I were to ask for straight answer, which one would you use in above situation?

Comment: I would use *her*.